# Jquery .css in a Newsslider

Tags: jquery

I made a Newsslider (that works) but I don't get the buttons 1 to 4 to highlight accordingly to the panel. They just change all the time. I assume it has something to do with the .css being processed immediatly. I assume I need to put the css calls into a timeout function. I am just not exactly sure how.

http://jsfiddle.net/BkZyD/

```
var whichpanel = 1;
$('.news-numbers div:nth-child(' + whichpanel + ')').css({
 'background-color': '#00F'
}, 5000);

 function newsslider() {
 if (whichpanel < 4) {
     $('.news-numbers div:nth-child(' + whichpanel + ')').css({
         'background-color': '#243239'
     }, 5000);

     $('.news-slider').delay(3000).animate({
         'margin-top': '-=250px'
     }, function () {

     });
     whichpanel += 1;
     $('.news-numbers div:nth-child(' + whichpanel + ')').css({
         'background-color': '#00F'
     }, 5000);

 } else if (whichpanel >= 4) {
     $('.news-slider').delay(3000).animate({
         'margin-top': '0'
     }, 2000);
     whichpanel = 1;
 }

 setTimeout(newsslider, 0);
}

newsslider();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the combined use of [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) and delay; using them the newsslider function is repeated every 10ms and the `whichpanel` incremented.
You animate smoothly your div using delay and animation, but the `news-numbers` changes continuosly.

For doing a continuos loop is better to use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setinterval) and increment the `whichpanel` inside the animation function. With this you don't require any other delay or timeout.

Code:

```
 var whichpanel = 1;
 $('.news-numbers div:nth-child(1)').css({
     'background-color': 'red'
 });

 function newsslider() {

     if (whichpanel < 4) {

         $('.news-slider').animate({
             'margin-top': '-=250px'
         }, function () {
             whichpanel += 1;
             $('.news-numbers div').css({
                 'background-color': 'black'
             });
             $('.news-numbers div:nth-child(' + whichpanel + ')').css({
                 'background-color': 'red'
             });

         });

     } else {

         $('.news-slider').animate({
             'margin-top': '0'
         }, 1000, function () {
             whichpanel = 1;
             $('.news-numbers div').css({
                 'background-color': 'black'
             });
             $('.news-numbers div:nth-child(1)').css({
                 'background-color': 'red'
             });

         });
     }

 }

 var int = self.setInterval(function () {
     newsslider()
 }, 3000);
```

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/p4U3B/2/

Comment: Oh okay, thanks. It seems that alternatively I could also just take out the 3000ms from the delays and add those to the timeout function?